# How to check if a string contains brackets ")("?

Tags: string, bash, shell, escaping

I'm trying to check if an input string contains parentheses, which are: `()[]{}`.

I wrote the following code:

```
#!/bin/bash
str="$1"
if [ -z "$str" ]; then
  echo "Usage: $(basename $0) string"
  exit 1
fi
if [[ "$str" == *['\{''}''\[''\]''('')']* ]];
then
  echo "True"
else
  echo "False"
fi
```

If the string contains any of these: `[]{}` then the output is correct but if the string contains `()` then I get an error:

```
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

These are the things I've tried so far:

```
*['\(''\)']*
*['()']*
*[()]*
```

Any idea how it should be written?

Edit #1:

```
[root@centolel ~]# date
Tue Nov  3 18:39:37 IST 2015
[root@centolel ~]# bash -x asaf.sh {
+ str='{'
+ '[' -z '{' ']'
+ [[ { == *[{}\[\]\(\)]* ]]
+ echo True
True
[root@centolel ~]# bash -x asaf.sh (
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
[root@centolel ~]#
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this `glob` pattern with `()` and `[]` escaped inside `[...]`:

```
[[ $str == *[{}\(\)\[\]]* ]] && echo "yes" || echo "no"
```

**Testing:**

```
str='abc[def' && [[ $str == *[{}\(\)\[\]]* ]] && echo "yes" || echo "no"
yes

str='abc}def' && [[ $str == *[{}\(\)\[\]]* ]] && echo "yes" || echo "no"
yes

str='abc[def' && [[ $str == *[{}\(\)\[\]]* ]] && echo "yes" || echo "no"
yes

str='abc(def' && [[ $str == *[{}\(\)\[\]]* ]] && echo "yes" || echo "no"
yes

str='abc)def' && [[ $str == *[{}\(\)\[\]]* ]] && echo "yes" || echo "no"
yes

str='abc{}def' && [[ $str == *[{}\(\)\[\]]* ]] && echo "yes" || echo "no"
yes

str='abc}def' && [[ $str == *[{}\(\)\[\]]* ]] && echo "yes" || echo "no"
yes

str='abcdef' && [[ $str == *[{}\(\)\[\]]* ]] && echo "yes" || echo "no"
no
```

Comment: Thanks! I've tried changing my code from: `*['\{''}''\[''\]''('')']*` to `*[{}\(\)\[\]]*` but I still get the same error, got any idea why?

Comment: Instead of `sh -x asaf.sh` use `bash -x asaf.sh`

Comment: @ItaiGanot if you call your script with `sh`, it will behave differently. Call it with `bash` instead.

Comment: Send argument in quotes e.g. `bash asaf.sh '('`

Comment: With quotes it works. Is there any way to avoid the requirement of the quotes?

Comment: Quotes are needed otherwise shell attempts to interpret `(` as some shell construct like array.